# $stmt->bind_param($params) possible?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement, switch-statement

My function looks like that.

```
if (isset($_POST['type'])) {
    switch ($_POST['type']) {
        case "qsubject":
            $sql = "SELECT id, name FROM chapters WHERE subject_id=?";
            break;
        case "qchapters":
            $sql = "SELECT id, name FROM sections WHERE subject_id=? AND chapter_id=?";
            break;
        case "qsections":
            $sql = "SELECT id, name FROM paragraphs WHERE subject_id=? AND chapter_id=? AND section_id=?";
            break;
    }
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql) or die($db->error());
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        $stmt->bind_result($chp_id, $name);
        echo '<option value="#"></option>';
        while ($stmt->fetch())
            echo '<option value="' . $chp_id . '">' . $name . '</option>';
    }
    else
        echo 0;
    $stmt->close();
}
```

For every switch case `$params` (`$stmt->bind_param($params);`) must be different.

So what I want to do is to create `$params` inside `switch`

```
$params='"i"'.$id;
```

Then use it like this

```
$stmt->bind_param($params);
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know if that is what you want, but just put the prepare() and bind_param() calls inside the case-statement:

```
if (isset($_POST['type'])) {
    switch ($_POST['type']) {
        case "qsubject":
            $sql = "SELECT id, name FROM chapters WHERE subject_id=?";
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql) or die($db->error());
            $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
            break;
        case "qchapters":
            $sql = "SELECT id, name FROM sections WHERE subject_id=? AND chapter_id=?";
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql) or die($db->error());
            $stmt->bind_param("ii", $id, $chapter_id);
            break;
        case "qsections":
            $sql = "SELECT id, name FROM paragraphs WHERE subject_id=? AND chapter_id=? AND section_id=?";
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql) or die($db->error());
            $stmt->bind_param("iii", $id, $chapter_id, $section_id);
            break;
    }
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        $stmt->bind_result($chp_id, $name);
        echo '<option value="#"></option>';
        while ($stmt->fetch())
            echo '<option value="' . $chp_id . '">' . $name . '</option>';
    }
    else
        echo 0;
    $stmt->close();
}
```

you are doing 3 different queries, so it's totally fine to have 3 different prepare()-calls.

if you can't use this approach you could also create a simple array to store your parameters.

```
$params = array();
case "qsubject":
     $params[] = array("type"=>"i", "value"=>$id);
     break;

case "qchapters":
     $params[] = array("type"=>"i", "value"=>$id);
     $params[] = array("type"=>"i", "value"=>$chapter_id);
     break;

// probably won't work, see text below.
foreach ($params as $param)
     $stmt->bind_param($param["type"], $param["value"]);
```

it seems that you have to provide all the variables when calling the bind_param statement. you can still call bind_param with a variable count of arguments. see the comments on http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might bind params within each case statement, something like below:

```
switch ($_POST['type']) {
    case "qsubject":
        $sql = "SELECT id, name FROM chapters WHERE subject_id=?";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql) or die($db->error());
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
        break;
    case "qchapters":
        $sql = "SELECT id, name FROM sections WHERE subject_id=? AND chapter_id=?";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql) or die($db->error());
        $stmt->bind_param("ii", $id, $id1);
        break;
    case "qsections":
        $sql = "SELECT id, name FROM paragraphs WHERE subject_id=? AND chapter_id=? AND section_id=?";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql) or die($db->error());
        $stmt->bind_param("iii", $id, $id1, $id2);
        break;
}
```

Comment: I know this. But maybe it's possible to get rid off extra piece of code with my idea?

Comment: Well, it will anyways require extra code to get rid of the redundant code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it won't help the OP anymore, but my guess what he really wanted is to dynamically create an array (with variable length of parameters) to bind.

This can be done by using

```
call_user_func_array()
```

short example:

```
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'),
  array_merge(array($bindParamsString), $paramsToBind));
```

where the variable `$bindParamsString` corresponds to the types of parameters (e.g. 'iis') and the parameter `$paramsToBind` is an array holding references to values you want to bind:

```
$paramsToBind = array(&myFirstValue [,&mySecondValue [,..]);
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it's quite possible, but I would suggest not to use mysqli and move to PDO, which works exactly the way you ask:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($params);
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```